# I ran away from Tapu Lele-- Will it respawn?

Tags: pokemon-sun-moon

I ran away from Tapu Lele in Pokemon Moon cause I didn't wanna fight it yet now the statue says nothing happens when I touch it. Will it re-spawn on it's own or do I have to reset to before the encounter?

Is it one per game if I accidentally kill it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[This site](http://www.justpushstart.com/2016/11/pokemon-sun-moon-tapu-lele/) says that if you defeat it, you can rechallenge it by defeating the Elite Four.

> If at some point you defeated it instead of catching it, you can re-challenge it by defeating the Elite Four.

Although you ran away, I assume you can do the same thing.  [This Forum](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/187276-pokemon-sun/74637025) says that if you ran away, you can defeat the Elite Four again to get a rematch as well.